# Simple Jquery not working in Firefox 16.0.2

Tags: jquery, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox doesn’t fire $(document).ready(function() {](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327150/firefox-doesnt-fire-document-readyfunction)

Below code not prompt message box when i used Firefox and i've tested the below code with IE and Chrome, it does prompt message box. Anyone experience this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/jscript" ></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('test');  
})       
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script type="text/jscript">`

Comment: just for anyone have same environment like me (.net), you might interest to know other possible reason cause it not working http://instinctcoder.com/why-simple-jquery-not-working/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change both script tag's type attribute to `type="text/javascript"` instead of `type="text/jscript"`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('test');  
    });       
</script>
```

Comment: type="text/javascript" is not needed anymore and can safely be removed

Answer (score 3):

Remove the attribute :  `type="text/jscript"` or replace it with `text/javascript` and see if that works

Answer (score 1):

error is here:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
```

It should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

type="text/jscript" could be the problem. If you change that to type="text/javascript" it does seem to work.